# Extract reference levels from linear mixed model

Tags: r, lme4

How do I extract the combination of reference levels for fixed factors in `lmer()` ?

Let's assume we have model:

```
fx <- lmer(RT ~ size + response + noise:size + noise:prime
                 + (1+noise|subject) + (1+noise|picture),
                 data=df, REML=FALSE)
```

Levels in `df`:

```
levels(size) = c('1', '2')
levels(noise) = c('0', '4')
levels(prime) = c('yes', 'incorr', 'no')
levels(response) = c('left', 'up', 'right', 'down')
levels(picture) = rep(1:7)
levels(subject) = rep(1:20)
```

In model's summary we see:

```
Fixed effects:
                               Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)                 381.409     38.675   9.862
size_2                      -46.914     14.814  -3.167
responce_up                  60.028     17.633   3.404
responce_right                5.640     16.764   0.336
responce_down                87.455     17.073   5.123
size_1:noise_4               91.443     38.346   2.385
size_2:noise_4              141.050     37.765   3.735
noise_0:prime_incorr          4.758     22.278   0.214
noise_4:prime_incorr         72.849     35.988   2.024
noise_0:prime_no             16.736     22.407   0.747
noise_4:prime_no             90.058     34.427   2.616
```

Now we need to count what effect size every fixed factor causes if it included to model.

If I understand correctly `(Intercept)` estimates target variable based on levels of fixed effects chosen in alphabetical order. 
It is quite easy to guess this levels if we have only simple fixed factors. But what `(Intercept)` contains if we also use interactions like `size:nose` in a model?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your interpretation of the intercept. As in [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80797/intercepts-reference-in-linear-mixed-effect-model-what-to-choose) Cross Validated post:
 
"The intercept is the predicted value of the dependent variable when all the independent variables are 0." 

This interpretation should not change when including interactions.

Comment: @r.bot but how factor variable can be 0? To make it "zero" lmer choose default level, as I know..

Comment: It would be the reference level of the factor. So '1' in the case of `size`, '0' in the case of `noise`, etc.

Comment: **R** uses first level in a factor as the reference level, as briefly noted by @ r.bot above. You can use the `relevel` function if you wish to alter this. For instance, perhaps you would like a different interpretation of coefficients.